# Which of these relations are maps?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations

List all relations $\{a,b\} \to \{c,d\}$, assuming $a \neq b$ and $c \neq d$. Which of them are maps?

So I know the cartesian product gives $\{(a,c),(a,d),(b,c),(b,d)\}$.

And the relations will be subsets of this cartesian product:

$1) \emptyset,\\ 
2)\{(a,c)\},\\
3)\{(a,d)\},\\
4)\{(b,c)\},\\
5)\{(b,d)\},\\
6)\{(a,c),(a,d)\},\\
7)\{(a,c),(b,c)\},\\
8)\{(a,c),(b,d)\},\\
9)\{(a,d),(b,c)\},\\
10)\{(a,d),(b,d)\},\\
11)\{(b,c),(b,d)\},\\
12)\{(a,c),(a,d),(b,c)\},\\
13)\{(a,c),(a,d),(b,d)\},\\
14)\{(a,c),(b,c),(b,d)\},\\
15)\{(a,d),(b,c),(b,d)\},\\
16)\{(a,c),(a,d),(b,c),(b,d)\}.
 $

Now for maps, what do I need to look for specifically? Why is the empty set or set (2) just below it not a map? When I look at relation (2), I see an element where the first component is from A = {a,b}, the second component is from B = {c,d} and the first component maps to a unique second component. I know I'm wrong, but why?

Following that, why is relation (12) not a map?

And lastly, why is relation (6) not a map?

Comment: Do you know any *definition* of a map? It is just a matter of applying this definition.

Comment: @drhab: I do. I described my understanding of a map above. Unfortunately, it seems a bit abstract to me and I'm struggling to wrap my head around it. If you were to answer 1 or 2 of the questions above, it may help. For example, why is relation (2) not a map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relation $R\subseteq X\times Y$ is a map if and only for **every** $x\in X$ there is **exactly one** $y\in Y$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle\in R$.

Here $X=\{a,b\}$ and $Y=\{c,d\}$ with $a\neq b$ and $c\neq d$.

So in this context $R$ is a map if it is of the form $\{\langle a,y\rangle,\langle b,z\rangle\}$ with $y,z\in\{c,d\}$.

It is not empty (relation 1 is not a map).

It must contain one of the pairs (not both) $\langle b,c\rangle$ and $\langle b,d\rangle$ (relation 2 is not a map).

Comment: Okay, I really think I'm getting it now, but with reference to your last point, why does it have to contain one of those two ordered pairs, i.e., why is one ordered pair not enough?

Comment: Never mind, I get it! We have to account for EVERY x in X, so we have to have exactly two ordered pairs in the set because there are two elements in set A. Right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: It was just that one niggle that was getting me. Now I understand perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help. You are welcome.